# Pass input/variables to command/script over SSH using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh, paramiko

I am having issues passing responses to a bash script on a remote server over SSH.

I am writing a program in Python 3.6.5 that will SSH to a remote Linux server.
On this remote Linux server there is a bash script that I am running which requires user input to fill in. For whatever reason I cannot pass a user input from my original python program over SSH and have it fill in the bash script user input questions.

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
import SSH

hostname = 'xxx'
username = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'

class Connect:
    def module(self):
        name = input()
        connection = SSH.SSH(hostname, username, password)
        connection.sendCommand(
            'cd xx/{}/xxxxx/ && source .cshrc && ./xxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx'.format(path))
```

SSH.py

```
from paramiko import client

class SSH:

    client = None

    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
        print("Login info sent.")
        print("Connecting to server.")
        self.client = client.SSHClient()    # Create a new SSH client
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(
            address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False) # connect

    def sendCommand(self, command):
        print("Sending your command")
        # Check if connection is made previously
        if (self.client):
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
            while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
                # Print stdout data when available
                if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    # Retrieve the first 1024 bytes
                    alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                    while stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                        # Retrieve the next 1024 bytes
                        alldata += stdout.channel.recv(1024)


                    # Print as string with utf8 encoding
                    print(str(alldata, "utf8"))
        else:
            print("Connection not opened.")
```

The final `/xxxxxx` in class `Connect` is the remote script that is launched.
It will open a text response awaiting a format such as

> What is your name:

and I cannot seem to find a way to properly pass the response to the script from my `main.py` file within the class `Connect`.

Every way I have tried to pass `name` as an argument or a variable the answer seems to just disappear (likely since it is trying to print it at the Linux prompt and not within the bash script)

I think using the `read_until` function to look for the `:` at the end of the question may work.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the input that your command needs to the `stdin`:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
stdin.write(name + '\n')
stdin.flush()
```

---

*(You will of course need to propagate the `name` variable from `module` to `sendCommand`, but I assume you know how to do that part).*

Comment: this worked, thank you very much! I was not aware of the .write function for stdin