# Execute command/script using different shell in SSH/Paramiko

Tags: python, bash, shell, ssh, paramiko

I am rather new to Linux and Paramiko, but the issue I am having is anytime I attempt to change a shell the remote Paramiko session will hang.

The remote host is in `/etc/csh` by default
I am running various scripts, some require `csh` and others require `bash`. Any of my scripts running in `csh` work properly since the remote host is in `csh` by default.

To run the other scripts I need to be in `bash`.
Whenever I attempt to change the shell using `bash` or `/bin/bash` paramiko connection will simply hang. I am using the following command to verify shells prior to connection and after attempting to temporarily change the shell to see what works, but nothing has. This is using **Paramiko** and **Python 3.6.5**.
**Note:** this also fails the other way around; if I put the remote host in `bash` by default it will fail to switch to `csh`

**main.py**

```
connection = SSH.SSH(hostname, username, password)
connection.changeShell('echo $0 ; echo $shell; /bin/bash ; echo $shell ; echo $0')
```

This has also been tried as just `bash` and `chsh`

**SSH.py**

```
class SSH:
    client = None

    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
        print("Login info sent.")
        print("Connecting to server.")
        self.client = client.SSHClient()    # Create a new SSH client
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(address, username=username,
                password=password, look_for_keys=False) # connect

    def changeShell(self, command):
        print("Sending your command")
        # Check in connection is made previously
        if (self.client):
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
            while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
                # Print stdout data when available
                if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    # Retrieve the first 1024 bytes
                    alldata = stdout.channel.recv(2048)
                    while stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                        # Retrieve the next 1024 bytes
                        alldata += stdout.channel.recv(2048)

                    # Print as string with utf8 encoding
                    print(str(alldata, "utf8"))

            stdin.close()
            stdout.close()
            stderr.close()

        else:
            print("Connection not opened.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your question has nothing to do with Paramiko. Try to paste your command in SSH terminal - It won't work either.*

---

The syntax `aaa ; bbb` executes the commands one *after* another. `bbb` won't be executed until `aaa` finishes. Similarly, `/bin/bash ; echo $shell` executes `bash` and the `echo` won't be executed until `bash` finishes, what it never does, hence the hang.

You actually do not want to execute `echo` *after* `bash` - you want to execute `echo` *within* `bash`.

If you want to execute a script/commands within a different shell, you have three options:

- Specify the shell that the script needs in the script itself using [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) - This the the right way for scripts.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```
- Execute the script/commands using shell command-line:

  ```
  /bin/bash script.sh
  ```

  or

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "command1 ; command2 ; ..."
  ```
- Write the script/command to be executed to a shell input, like I've shown you in your previous question:

  [Pass input/variables to bash script over SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50749745/850848)

Comment: Thanks for the answer martin - I went ahead and tested it directly in SSH as you mentioned. You are right it still does hang on `bash` as you mentioned. You mentioned the idea of using ; is to execute one after another but I want to execute WITHIN bash. `connection.changeShell('echo $0 ; echo $shell; bash ; /bin/bash -c "echo $shell" ; /bin/bash -c "echo $0"')`

Comment: Is that what you mean by the third option? The problem is since this is paramiko I need to pass all of the commands/arguments in one line. The remote session starts in `csh` and I need to change to `bash` and then `source ./.bashrc` before launching the actual script that is on the host. Using a shebang would not help since I am having the error with `source ./.bashrc`

Comment: You can do `/bin/bash -c "source ./.bashrc ; ./script.sh"`

Comment: Ha I just did that as you mentioned and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!