# Paramiko with subprocess

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, paramiko

I want to run a program on a remote server and send command to it from my computer using subprocess and Paramiko. Is below can be usefull?

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('host', username='user', password="password")
myprogramme = subprocess.Popen("myprogramme.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
myprogramme.stdin.write(ssh_stdout.read())
myprogramme.communicate("some_inputs\n")
myprogramme.kill
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot run a program on a remote server over SSH with [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Use [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) to execute your command.

Then you can feed your command to the process using the returned `stdin`:
[Pass input/variables to command/script over SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50749745/850848)