# Executing commands of interactive tool and reading their output with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, stdout, paramiko, readline

I am preparing a code to access a remote server using ssh with Paramiko and to run some commands and see the output of stdout.

I have tested the code with a Ubuntu server and it worked perfectly, but when I tested the code with a different server (which is a Windows server and the interface to a telecommunication machine) the stdout is not read,
The (*"Successfully executed command on remote server"*) is printed but the following (*"lines are read"*)
is not printed So I concluded that the code is hanging at `stdout=stdout.readlines()`
The code is copied below, can you please help me figuring out what could be the reason behind this failure?

I want also to add that if I use PuTTY to execute the commands on that server I get the correct output.

```
import paramiko
import os
user_name = "****"
passwd = "******"
ip = "*.*.*.*"

print ("Please wait creating ssh client ...")
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()     #Create sshclient instance
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print ("Please wait, connecting to remote server")
ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip,username=user_name,password=passwd)
cmd="mml \n command2"
print ("Please wait, executing command on remote server")
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
print ("Successfully executed command on remote server")
stdout=stdout.readlines()
print ("lines are read")
stdout="".join(stdout)
ssh_client.close()
print ("Connection closed")
print (stdout)
os.system("pause")
```

Comment: Are you sure that no exception is thrown? + Do you get the problem with any command or with some specific commands only? + What kind of server is that?

Comment: Hello, yes there is no exception just hanging without any output. This is a windows server communicating with another telecom machine via internal protocol, after login the first command is mml, (for man machine languague), then I can type some specific commands for this telecom provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that you are executing is interactive. When started, it waits for subcommands. While you execute it and wait for the command to finish (by calling `readlines`). What never happens.

You have to feed the subcommands to your command to have it do something.
See [Pass input/variables to command/script over SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50749745/850848).

You will also have to make the command quit (by sending a subcommand like `exit`/`quit`/`bye`).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, do I have to add the subcommands in write.stdin: I have added the following lines: stdin.write("subcommand") and stdin.flush() before the stdout.stdout.readlines(), but still the same result,I feel like I have to read more about using paramiko but I don't know exactly which part I need to search.

Comment: 1) You have missed the newline `+ '\n'`. 2) You have tell your command (`mml`) to close before you call `readlines`. Typically by sending `"exit\n"` or `"bye\n"` or `"quit\n"`.

Comment: Now the stdout.readlines is executed, even if it gives empty output [] but I guess this is another problem, I believe is due to the location of the second ssh_client.exec_command("exit;") which erases the output of the mml command.

Comment: I have added the modified code in my question above

Comment: You have to send the `exit` to the `mml`, the same way you send the `command1`.

Comment: Hi , I have executed the ("exit;") command using stdin.write() as suggested but then the code is hanging at the stdout.readlines() again.       Then I tried to close the ssh_client before stdout.readlines() and this time the stdout.readlines() was executed but then print (stdout) is giving empty output   []

Comment: Again, should there be the new-line? `"exit\n"`

Comment: Yes, I have added the \n for a new line as follows: stdin.write("exit;\n")

Comment: And does `exit` really work for `mml`? Did you test it? Also did you try using `readline` in a loop to see what output (or error) do you get back?

Comment: Yes, the exit; commands works, I tested it using putty.   I will try to use readline in a loop

Comment: Hello I am close! I have removed the line:  stdout=stdout.readline() and replaced it with a loop as follows:           for line in stdout:              print(stdout.readline())      and now it prints the output of the command but 1/2 the lines, I mean it prints the 1st 3rd 5th lines etc but not the 2nd 4th 6th lines

Comment: Finally I got the desired output, I have simply used :  for line in stdout:       print (line),         so I didn't read from stdout, a little weird but it worked :)  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: But your loop must still hang after the last line, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes you are right, the last line of the output is : exit;        I have added two prints after the print (line) but they are not printed , it seems that stdout is still waiting for another command...