# Use paramiko to enter IO to remote CLI program

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I have a command line Python program which takes user input and adds it to a config file. When run it prompts the user to enter one config value at a time. The user enters the value and hits enter to get prompted for the next value. Examples of these values are as follows:

```
Please enter configured host IP:
Please enter the username for the account:
Please enter password for the user:
```

This program runs on a remote server and is executed as one part of a manual process. I'm trying to automate this process and am using the `paramiko` library to run this command. I use `exec_command` to run it. Can I send the values that the program prompts for using `paramiko` and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```py
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(
    'sudo python3 {}initialSetup.py'.format(self.backup_directory),
    60)
ssh_stdin.write('1.2.3.4\n')
ssh_stdin.write('username\n')
ssh_stdin.write('password\n')
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749745/pass-input-variables-to-command-script-over-ssh-using-python-paramiko) for details.

Comment: Please, instead of posting a duplicate answer, accept that your question is duplicate and consider upvoting the duplicate question and its answers.