# SSH to server and from there SCP to another server

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, scp, openssh

I want to SSH to a Linux server and from there, do a SCP copy to one ESXI server. Both need username and password.

1. Connect to Linux box:

   ```
   ssh_linux = paramiko.SSHClient()
   ssh_linux.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   ssh_linux.connect(linux_host, username=linux_user, password=linux_password)
   ```
2. SCP:

   ```
   scp_command = f"scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {local_file_path} {esxi_user}@{esxi_host}:{remote_file_path}"
   logging.info(f"{scp_command}")
   stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_linux.exec_command(scp_command)
   scp_exit_status = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()

   if scp_exit_status == 0:
       logging.info(f"File {file} copied successfully.")
   else:
       logging.error(f"Error copying. SCP command failed with exit code {scp_exit_status}")
       logging.error(f"SCP STDOUT: {stdout.read().decode()}")
       logging.error(f"SCP STDERR: {stderr.read().decode()}")
       ssh_linux.close()
   ```

How to send password of the ESXI host to the `scp` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Pass input/variables to command/script over SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50749745/850848)

Though OpenSSH tools do not accept password from stdin. You have to fake terminal by passing `get_pty=True` to [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command).

---

Overal, I do not think this is the right approach.

Instead, I'd use port forwarding. See [Nested SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35304525/850848).

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

*And for the same reason, do not use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.*