# How to enter a command twice with paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I use paramiko package in python, and I have to input command('pcoip-list-licese') and input password('Password1!').

When in 192.168.3.1 server same command, the 192.168.3.1 server request password.

[image: Password Prompt Image]

The ssh connect is okay, but after command input 'pcoip-list-licenses' password command does not work, so how can I modify this code?

```
import paramiko
 

Host = "192.168.3.1"
port = 22
ID = "root"
PASSWD = "password1!"


try:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
    ssh.connect(Host, port=port, username=ID , password = PASSWD)
    
    print("ssh connect")
    print("Start verify License")
    
    #check License
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('pcoip-list-licenses')
    
    #input password
    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("Password1!")
    #list_install_result = ssh_stdout.readlines()
    
    #for i in list_install_result:    
    #   print(i)

    #list_install_result.clear()

except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Comment: This has been asked zillion times already. For example here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50749745/850848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's the `pcoip-list-licenses` command requesting the password, you'd have to write it into that `stdin` you get, e.g.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('pcoip-list-licenses')
stdin.write("password1!\n")
stdin.flush()
print(stdout.read().decode())
print(stderr.read().decode())
```

Comment: really thank you! it works! I will study the code you gave me. I didn't explain the question very well, but thank you for suggesting a solution.