Running Custom C over ssh with paramiko
I've been trying to automatically execute some compiled C code over an SSH session. However, I have a big issue; my C code requires user input, and therefore I need to be able to catch those inputs using an interactive shell?
However I would like my shell to kill itself and return to my Python script once the C code is done running.
This is how I handle it today, however I am unable to detect when my C code is done running.
def executeSSH(self, pathToFile, fileToExecute):
    hostname = "192.168.0.201"
    port = 22
    username = "root"
    password = "root"
    
    # Create SSH client
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    
    try:
        # Connect to the SSH server
        client.connect(hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password)
        
        # Start an interactive shell session
        transport = client.get_transport()
        channel = transport.open_session()
        channel.get_pty()
        channel.invoke_shell()

        stop_event = threading.Event()

        # Function to read from the channel and print to stdout
        def print_output(channel):
            while not stop_event.is_set():
                if channel.recv_ready():
                    output = channel.recv(1024).decode()
                    sys.stdout.write(output)
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                if channel.recv_stderr_ready():
                    error_output = channel.recv_stderr(1024).decode()
                    sys.stderr.write(error_output)
                    sys.stderr.flush()
                if channel.exit_status_ready():
                    break
                

        # Function to read user input and send to the channel
        def send_input(channel):
            try:
                while not stop_event.is_set():
                    if msvcrt.kbhit():
                        user_input = msvcrt.getch()
                        if user_input:
                            if user_input == 'q':  # Ctrl+D to exit
                                break
                            channel.send(user_input.decode())
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred in input thread: {e}")

        # Start threads for output and input
        output_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_output, args=(channel,))
        input_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_input, args=(channel,))
        output_thread.start()
        input_thread.start()
        
        # Send the commands to navigate to the directory and execute the file
        channel.send(f'{pathToFile}/{fileToExecute}\n')
        
        # Wait for the program to complete
        output_thread.join()

        # Stop the input thread
        stop_event.set()
        input_thread.join()
        
        # Get the exit status of the remote command
        exit_status = channel.recv_exit_status()
        
        # Close the channel and client
        channel.close()
        client.close()
        
        return exit_status
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return -1

Do you guys know a way around this?

This makes very little sense. Why do you need a shell? Why doesn't your C program directly interact with the user if that's what you want?

Why are you using invoke_shell and not exec_command? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/55762006/850848

@tripleee i am running my c over a custom camera acquisition card from my company that is runing a modified version of linux, i need C to use hardware libraries, the only way for me to execute this code is through ssh, and i would like to automate connexion, selection of the code to run, through python to make a user friendly terminal-like interface, idk if that's clearer

@MartinPrikryl the program i am executing on the other side requires user inputs, using invoke shell is the only way i've found so far to allow user inputs

https://stackoverflow.com/q/50749745/850848

@MartinPrikryl that looks what i'm trying to do except i cannot predetermine the inputs i will send neither when i should send them, the routine i'm running is in C, and require the technician to plug cables, unplug them etc, and to report to the C program whenever he is done, what are the defects stc...
(edit: most of my inputs are "press enter to continue" like, but sometine requires to input full strings)

Sorry, I do not understand your problem. In your current code you are using invoke_shell + send, just replace that with exec_command + stdin.write.

As @MartinPrikryl has pointed out, when you use "invoke_shell", you are starting a shell session on the remote host, the shell will not automatically exit on completion of your C program, and hence you have to figure that out yourself.
You can achieve this by reading from the shell, and trying to find text within that would indicate your C program has completed running
You can create a function that returns true of false, depending on whether the remote C program has exited
def check_remote_prgm_completed(shell_output, exit_str):
    #check if an exit string that indicates completion of our
    #C program is in the output
    if exit_str in shell_output:
        return True
    return False

You can then call thus function from print_output like below:
def print_output(channel):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
    if channel.recv_ready():
    output = channel.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    sys.stdout.write(output)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    #Check if we have exit string in the output and exit
    if check_remote_prgm_completed(output, "Program exited"):
        break


While this might work, it's a hack and not a proper solution.
